# apache2.2 x mongrel proxy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, mongrel

I user apache2.2 mod_proxy_balancer + mongrel + rails2.3
Following error is occured.
"proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by"

I set this my httpd.conf

```
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1

SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong is that you shouldn't really be using apache + proxy + mongrel anymore. Everyone, including the big players like Twitter and 37Signals have made the switch to Passenger (mod_rails).

Passenger is way easier to setup and maintain than a pack of mongrels. I think it's probably faster too.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/mongrel-users/2007-October/004145.html

and try changing your BalanceMember entries to something such as this

BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:9000 max=1 keepalive=on acquire=1 timeout=1